# Rails 4: what is wrong with this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading an application to Rails 4 and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this method. The offender's the update method:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @doc.articles.find_index { |a| a.changed? }
      @doc.publications.destroy_all
    end
    if @doc.update_attributes(params[:doc])
      @doc.create_activity :update, owner: current_user
      if current_user.brand.editable? && params[:editing]
        format.html { redirect_to editing_url(@doc) }
      else 
        format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc.user.ftp, @doc) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Clicking `submit` generates this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in DocsController#update
```

and highlights this line:

```
respond_to do |format|
```

The create method works fine, it looks like this:

```
def create
  @doc = Doc.new(params[:doc])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @doc.save
      @doc.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
      if current_user.brand.editable? && params[:editing]
        format.html { redirect_to doc_editing_url(@doc) }
      else 
        format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc.user.ftp, @doc) }
      end
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts at all? I'm totally stuck.

Oh, I've got this private method as a `before_action` too, so it's not that:

```
private

def set_document
  @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
end
```

**EDIT**

I found this quasi-explanation:

> In Rails 4.0, ActionController::UnknownFormat is raised when the
>   action doesn't handle the request format. By default, the exception is
>   handled by responding with 406 Not Acceptable, but you can override
>   that now. In Rails 3, 406 Not Acceptable was always returned. No
>   overrides.

which makes me think it's something to do with routes, but my routes should be default if I've declared them like so, yes?

```
resources :docs, :except => [:new, :show] do
  get "adjust/:state" => "docs#adjust", :as => :adjust
  patch "editing" => "docs#editing", :as => :editing
  patch "reupdate/" => "docs#reupdate", :as => :reupdate
  get "pdf" => "docs#pdf", :as => :pdf
  collection { post :sort }
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding the JSON to the controller, i.e.:

```
format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc.user.ftp, @doc) }
format.json { render action: 'share', status: :created, location: @doc }
```

gives me a no method error and seems to redirect me back to the edit page:

```
Showing .../fin/app/views/docs/_form.html.erb where line #19 raised:
undefined method `covers?' for nil:NilClass
```

Really no idea what's going on here.

Comment: do you have a `remote: true` on your form? is it sent via JS? do you have a `respond_to :json` in your controller?

Comment: There's no `remote: true` in the form, and it's not sent via JS. There's no `respond_to :json` in my controller because as far as I know I don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason can be that if `@doc.update_attributes(params[:doc])` returns `false` there is no format block being executed in the update method.

Usually you are rendering the `edit` action in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only serving HTML then you don't need `respond_to` and `format.html` at all.